# Is there a tool for automated quality assurance for vector data captured on raster data?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, arcgis-desktop, data-quality

I wonder whether is any tool(or script) in ArcGIS or QGIS which allows to make an automated quality assurance for vector data captured on raster data?
vector data on binary raster:

[image]

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question, and by leaving this open to both ArcGIS for Desktop and QGIS answers you are effectively asking two.  I think you should [edit] it to focus on whichever you are more likely to use.  Also, I think your question needs more detail about your specific requirements.